# I need a help for Database select * sorting

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usOMS.png)

here is my table SQL Query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tea_suppliers
(
    Suppliers_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Name         VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    ID           VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Address      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    Mobile_No    VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Suppliers_ID)
);
```

I need to display S01,S02,...,S09,S010,S011  like pattern.
But select * from display pattern like S01,S010,S011,S02,...,S09 (see image)
Please tell there is any way to do that

Comment: Have you simple select with order by `suppliers_ID`?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM other_suppliers
ORDER BY Supplier_ID DESC LIMIT 1   ,, yes, but it displays S09 value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may sort on only the numeric portion of the `Suppliers_ID`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tea_suppliers
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(Suppliers_ID, 2) AS UNSIGNED);
```

Note that a better table design would be to make `Suppliers_ID` a pure numeric column.  Then you could simply order using this column without making a cast.

Comment: Correction `CAST(SUBSTR(SUPPLIERS_ID, 2) AS INT)`, INT or UNSIGNED